# Converting arabic word into binary codes in Eclipse editor

Tags: spring, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm working on a spring boot application,

I had an Arabic content. When I pasted that in a `.properties` file it converted into binary code.

```
test = \u0627\u062E\u062A\u0628\u0627\u0631
```

The actual value is **اختبار**.

What is the reason for this, and how can I view it in Arabic from Eclipse?

Comment: What IDE are you using ?

Comment: @AvijitBarua Spring Tool Suite 

Version: 3.9.2.RELEASE

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
file->Properties-> Resource -> Other -> utf-8
```

[image][image]

Comment: Not working. Current setting is same. "Text file encoding" to "Other : UTF-8".

Comment: updated in question, not working for me. Do I need to change file association ?